# Replace through JCL

Tags: jcl

I need your help to find a solution to below through a JCL.

I have a file, in that I need to find 6 characters irrespective of the position and if found I need to replace those 6 plus next 9 characters. For example input file is something like below:

```
XXXXXXABCDEFGHIJKLMNO                          XXXXXX123456789
ABPOPCHGXXXXXXZYXWVUTSR123456   XXXXXX987654321ZZZZ   88888888
```

Here, I have find characters starting with 'XXXXXX' and if found replace those 15 characters with 000000000000000. Thus my output file should be like:

```
000000000000000JKLMNO                          000000000000000
ABPOPCHG000000000000000123456   000000000000000ZZZZ   88888888 t
```

Please help.

Comment: There is no way to do this with JCL! You need to run a program such as Sort, or write a program, e.g. a REXX script and run this over the data. You'll need JCL if you want to run the program/script in a batch job instead of in foreground TSO. But JCL itself will not help you.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. I am working on a REXX code but can this be done using SORT. Please help. Thanks again.

Comment: I'm not fluent enough in sort's `IFTHEN` to tell you a sort based solution. The difficulty lies in the fact that the string "XXXXXX" can occur multiple times on a single record, it seems. Maybe some else can help out? I'd go for a REXX solution, if this task is not run very often, or over very large files. REXX might be too slow for the latter.